# Flutter: Buttons work in iOS Simulator but not macOS Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, cross-platform

I am working through some Flutter tutorials, and I am developing this simple "QuizApp."

I've pushed the project up to Github here: https://github.com/johnnyicon/adv_basics

There are two screens - the [StartScreen](https://github.com/johnnyicon/adv_basics/blob/main/lib/start_screen.dart) and the [QuestionsScreen](https://github.com/johnnyicon/adv_basics/blob/main/lib/questions_screen.dart).

The QuestionsScreen dynamically loads questions and for each question, displays a list of four possible answers as buttons.

```dart
import 'package:adv_basics/data/questions.dart';
import 'package:adv_basics/answer_button.dart';
import 'package:adv_basics/models/quiz_questions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class QuestionsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuestionsScreen({
    super.key, 
    required this.onSelectAnswer
  });

  final void Function(String answer) onSelectAnswer;

  @override
  State<QuestionsScreen> createState() {
    return _QuestionsScreenState();
  }
}

class _QuestionsScreenState extends State<QuestionsScreen> {

  var currentQuestionIndex = 0;

  void answerQuestion(String selectedAnswer) {
    widget.onSelectAnswer(selectedAnswer);
    setState((){
      currentQuestionIndex++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final QuizQuestion currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex];

    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(40),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Text(
              currentQuestion.text, 
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30),
            ...currentQuestion.getShuffledAnswers().map((answer){
              return AnswerButton(
                answerText: answer, 
                onTap: () {
                  answerQuestion(answer);
                },
              );
            }),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The questions are hardcoded into a list that is in a separate file named (`lib/data/questions.dart`)[https://github.com/johnnyicon/adv_basics/blob/main/lib/data/questions.dart]. Here is a snippet of the structure of the data from that file.

```dart
import 'package:adv_basics/models/quiz_questions.dart';
const questions = [
  QuizQuestion(
    'What are the main building blocks of Flutter UIs?',
    [
      'Widgets',
      'Components',
      'Blocks',
      'Functions',
    ],
  ),
... more questions and answers
```

You'll see in the `QuestionsScreen` code (near the bottom) that the list of buttons is actually a custom widget called [`AnswerButton`](https://github.com/johnnyicon/adv_basics/blob/main/lib/answer_button.dart) but there isn't anything magical happening in there. It's just an `ElevatedButton` that has its appearance customized (see below).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnswerButton extends StatelessWidget {
  // const AnswerButton(this.answerText, this.onTap, { super.key, });
  const AnswerButton({ 
    super.key, 
    required this.answerText, 
    required this.onTap 
  });

  final String answerText;
  final void Function() onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: onTap,
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 10, 
          horizontal: 40
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
        )
      ),
      child: Text(
        answerText, 
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So, when I run this in the macOS simulator, these buttons are entirely *unresponsive*. You can't click it. I put `print` statements into the function that is being called, and even used an anonymous function at one point, to see if maybe it was just a presentation issue, but neither of the functions were called and no print statements were made. However, when I run this project in the iOS simulator, the buttons work fine.

I'm not sure how to fix this because this seems like something with the way Flutter/Dart is compiling the code for different platforms.